# How to get object using JVMTI

Tags: jvmti

I am new to `JVMTI`. I am trying to get object size using `GetObjectSize` method .

But I am stuck .

Can I get the objects from the heap space using `JVMTI`?  Is `GetTag` function involved somewhere in order to do this ?

I know we can track object initialization quite easily. But , I want the objects within a specific interval.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate the heap space using

```
jvmtiError
IterateThroughHeap(jvmtiEnv* env,
        jint heap_filter,
        jclass klass,
        const jvmtiHeapCallbacks* callbacks,
        const void* user_data)
```

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/platform/jvmti/jvmti.html#IterateThroughHeap